# squid transparent proxy seems to "break" internet connectivity (http - port 80 only)

Tags: http, squid

I have had a firewall & proxy server running for the past 2 years.
it is based on `slackware64 - v14.0` and has generally been up  long periods of time between reboots. Up until recently it was working fine. No one else has access to this system and I had not fiddled with it for about 60 days.

Recently I was setting up a new laptop and realised that internet was SLOW while accessing webpages on it. Indeed `http` (port 80) sites would not load at all, `https` and other services/ports worked though.

Looking into it I realised that by restarting the squid proxy server everything works normally and it does for a while again. Then again after some time no http websites...
I tried remove the whole proxy cache and re-setting up the cache using `squid -z` to no avail. The problem seems to return.

the logs say nothing out of the ordinary (just TCP hits and misses mostly) , but it was weird that the log was 907MB in size (even though I have a logrotate for squid logs enabled from `squid.conf`). It could not find anything wrong in it, apart from why the rotation (which was working until 60 days ago) is not working..
Even though I did a manual rotate the problem still comes back, so I have disable the use of squid for the moment (by disabling the firewall redirection of port 80).

This is Most weird though and I don't know where to start looking. Has anyone had any problems with it?

Some updates:

The problem of breaking starts when I try to access any http website from a specific laptop (which connects to the internal wifi). There are other laptops, and mobile devices that connect to the internet through this wifi and even a desktop pc with a usb-wifi dongle, but when this laptop tries to access a webpage there is no http internet for anyone anymore.

firewall redirect line is the following:

`$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $LOCAL_IFACE -s $LOCAL_NET --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128 #TRANSP PROXY`

If I don't "touch" squid at all after it has stopped working, and I just comment the above line out and restart the firewall, internet is back up again.

Say then I uncomment it again. internet is gone once again.

while `squid` is "in the loop" : `sar 1 1000` returns:

```
02:56:51 AM     all      4.52      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00     94.47
02:56:52 AM     all      5.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     94.00
02:56:53 AM     all      5.00      0.00      1.00      2.50      0.00     91.50
02:56:54 AM     all      4.50      0.00      1.50      0.00      0.00     94.00
02:56:55 AM     all      4.50      0.00      1.50      0.00      0.00     94.00
02:56:56 AM     all      4.52      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00     94.47
02:56:57 AM     all      4.98      0.00      1.49      0.00      0.00     93.53
```

while `squid` is not "in the loop", `sar` returns :

```
02:58:36 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
02:58:37 AM     all      1.01      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00     98.49
02:58:38 AM     all      2.00      0.00      0.50      2.00      0.00     95.50
02:58:39 AM     all      1.00      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00     98.50
02:58:40 AM     all      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     98.00
02:58:41 AM     all      1.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     98.50
```

so user cpu usages is a little lower.

while all this is happening `iotop` shows `0.00%` disk usages for the squid threads...

additionally, the squid latest entries, seen with : `tail -f access.log` are:

```
1389834351.849    382 192.168.18.25 TCP_MISS/200 335 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/validate-body - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1389834353.197    388 192.168.18.25 TCP_MISS/200 335 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/validate-body - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1389834372.791    453 192.168.18.25 TCP_MISS/200 349 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/566948/editor-heartbeat/edit - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
```

the above is copied while squid is "out of the loop". and while squid is enabled through firewall:

```
1389834586.593    364 192.168.18.25 TCP_MISS/302 1538 GET http://log.dmtry.com/redir/140952/0/3316/100544580/55099663/210599/0/0/0/1.ver? - DIRECT/54.243.105.45 -
1389834586.634    167 192.168.18.25 TCP_MISS/200 38559 GET http://public.oneallcdn.com/img/api/socialize/providers/logo/sprite_35_35.png - DIRECT/93.184.220.20 image/png
1389834586.639    410 192.168.18.25 TCP_MISS/302 1563 GET http://log.dmtry.com/redir/560228/0/3316/100544579/55097980/858012/0/0/0/1.ver? - DIRECT/54.243.105.45 -
```

then I try to access something from the laptop (has ip address `192.168.18.186`) and I get this http://pastebin.com/FM9QLtRC

so I don't understand what is different before and after...

Moreover, when there is no internet, I can not even access the website of my ADSL modem which sits on the `inet` interface of my firewall / gateway server !

hope all these help someone with more knowledge on server administration

Comment: what about `sar`, `sysstat`, `dmesg`, memory etc. How much memory does squid consume while acting strangely? `iostat`, `iotop`, `top`? Any other weird things in log? does it swap?

Comment: i'm in slackware so no sysstat. also since I was not familiar with `sar` is there any specific test you would like me to run ? please see updated question about the rest.